# Android ICMP ping

Tags: java, android, networking

Is there a way to ping a host (standard Android or via NDK implementation), and get detailed info on the response? (time, ttl, lost packages, etc..)
I was thinking of some open source app that has this feature but can't find any...

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Afaik, sending ICMP ECHO requests needs **root** (i.e. the app that does it needs to be setuid) - and that's *not* currently possible in "stock" Android (hell, even the [InetAddress#isReachable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) method in Android is a [joke](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20106) that doesn't work according to spec).

A very basic example using /usr/bin/ping & Process - reading the ping results, using an AsyncTask:

```
public class PingActivity extends Activity {
    PingTask mTask;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mTask = new PingTask();
        // Ping the host "android.com"
        mTask.execute("android.com");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mTask.stop();
    }

    class PingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        PipedOutputStream mPOut;
        PipedInputStream mPIn;
        LineNumberReader mReader;
        Process mProcess;
        TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mPOut = new PipedOutputStream();
            try {
                mPIn = new PipedInputStream(mPOut);
                mReader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(mPIn));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                cancel(true);
            }

        }

        public void stop() {
            Process p = mProcess;
            if (p != null) {
                p.destroy();
            }
            cancel(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                mProcess = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command("/system/bin/ping", params[0])
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .start();

                try {
                    InputStream in = mProcess.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = mProcess.getOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int count;

                    // in -> buffer -> mPOut -> mReader -> 1 line of ping information to parse
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        mPOut.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        publishProgress();
                    }
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    mPOut.close();
                    mPIn.close();
                } finally {
                    mProcess.destroy();
                    mProcess = null;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            try {
                // Is a line ready to read from the "ping" command?
                while (mReader.ready()) {
                    // This just displays the output, you should typically parse it I guess.
                    mText.setText(mReader.readLine());
                }
            } catch (IOException t) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nope. I have unrooted phone, the Net Ping app is working as designed.

Comment: then it's probably executing the ping command using [java.lang.Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) - that command is setuid and can give you the TTL if you parse the output - doing it straight from Java is not going to work (the example in Process is in fact running the ping command).

Comment: can you execute the 'ping' command with java.lang.Process without root?

Comment: Yup, it's [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and will do the parts required to have root. You'll have to parse the continuous string input that it will generate - but the appended example above shows how to use a piped input/outputstream to process the result on the UI-thread whilst running the command in an AsyncTask.

Comment: Added a fix to the example, it will now also actually *stop* the AsyncTask properly (oops, forgot that Process ignores interrupts)

Comment: If the PING Process fails it should set the Process.exitValue to be non-zero. Note you should probably get it using Process.waitFor to be sure PING has finished. This stops you having to parse the text output, which is tedious and fragile.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to execute ping command without root.
Spawns a 'sh' process first, and then execute 'ping' in that shell, the code:

```
p = new ProcessBuilder("sh").redirectErrorStream(true).start();

DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("ping -c 10 " + host + '\n');
os.flush();

// Close the terminal
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();

// read ping replys
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

It works fine on my HTC device with CyanogenMod 7.1.0 (Android 2.3.7)

Comment: Without -w <# seconds> on the ping command I get a hang if unpingable potentially - Just a warning for those trying this..

Comment: -1 It's a poor design to create a shell, then launch ping.  It involves more parsing and more difficulty passing in input.  It's better to launch ping directly.

Answer (score 0):

Having Root access isn't necessary for ICMP on Android for a long time now.

There is [icmp4a library](https://github.com/marsounjan/icmp4a) (my library) which works on Android 23+ and doesn't involve executing `ping` command via `Runtime.exec()` or using Android NDK.

Example:

1. **Get the library**

```
implementation "com.marsounjan:icmp4a:1.0.0"
```

2. **Single ICMP Ping**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  val status = icmp.ping( host = "8.8.8.8")
  val result = status.result
  when (result) {
    is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
    is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
  }
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:22:48.515 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 12 ms
```

3. **Multiple ICMP Pings with specified interval**

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
try {
  icmp.pingInterval(
      "8.8.8.8",
      count = 5,
      intervalMillis = 1000
  )
    .onEach { status ->
        val result = status.result
        when (result) {
          is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
          is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
        }
    }
      .launchIn(viewModelScope)
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Logcat output

```
2024-01-26 16:29:16.633 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:17.577 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:18.598 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 17 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:19.614 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 15 ms
2024-01-26 16:29:20.630 ICMP D  google.com(8.8.8.8) 64 bytes - 13 ms
```