# Pass MotionEvent ActionDown coordinates to inner class (AsyncTask)

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, coordinates, motionevent

as the title says, I want to be able to pass the coordinates given on `ACTION_DOWN` to the `onPostExecute` method of my `AsyncTask` inner class. I have been trying to do this for the past two days without success. How do I go about this? Any help is appreciated :)

Here is my code:

```
package io.music.ui.settings;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import io.music.R;
import io.music.ui.base.BaseFragment;
import io.music.ui.main.MainActivity;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.x;


public class SettingsFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;
    public float x = 0.95f;
    //String xx = String.format("%.2f", x);
    public float y = 0;
    float x1, x2, y1, y2;

    List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    x = 2f * (event.getX() / v.getWidth()) - 1f;
                    y = -2f * (event.getY() / v.getHeight()) + 1f;

                    //x1 = x - 0.1f;
                    //x2 = x + 0.1f;
                    //y1 = y - 0.1f;
                    //y2 = y + 0.1f;
                    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    textView.setText(String.format("%.2f", x));
                    TextView textView2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    textView2.setText(String.format("%.2f", y));
                }

                mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(getActivity(), data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

                return false;
            }

        });


        new AsyncFetch().execute();

        return view;
    }




    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("http://example.com/Subjects2.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file

                conn.setDoOutput(true);


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread


            pdLoading.dismiss();


            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String xx= String.format("%.2f", x);
                    if(json_data.getString("X").equals(xx) ) {
                        DataFish fishData = new DataFish();

                        fishData.fishName = json_data.getString("SongName");
                        fishData.catName = json_data.getString("X");
                        fishData.sizeName = json_data.getString("Y");

                        data.add(fishData);

                    }
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

EDIT: I also want to specify that I am trying to get the variables `x` and `y` to the `onPostExecute` method and I have put a value for `x` just to test if the json output is correct. I want the `x` coordinate to come from the `TouchListener`.

Comment: not clear what you're trying to do, you're executing the `AsyncTask` before the user clicks on the screen, so you don't have any coordinates to give your task yet. did you mean calling `execute` within the `TouchListener`?

Comment: @marmor When it is inside the TouchListener, everytime I tape on the screen it loads the entire json output again into the recyclerview. It's why I put it outside. I realise it's probably a bad idea (sorry I'm new to android developemnt and java). How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should indeed load the json file only once, when the activity/fragment loads, but you may want to display some progress bar while the file loads and the fragment isn't ready yet to accept user touches.
(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235277/android-asynctask-progressbar-and-i-o))

When the file finishes downloading, and you go into onPostExecute:

1. Change `jArray` to be a class field, and store `new JSONArray(result);` in it so it can be accessed from anywhere in the class.
2. hide your progress-bar, and display the real layout to the user.

Then in your `onTouch` implementation, use the value in `jArray` to perform that for loop that populates your RecyclerView (move that code from `onPostExecute` to the `onTouch` listener)

Comment: I managed to do it by simply putting the AsyncTask inside the onTouch listener but your solution seems better so I will implement it. Thank you so much :D